# Spyder not terminating tkinkter mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I am starting with python and I'm using Spyder 3.9.13 with Python 3.9

When beginning with the GUI design I have run in one problem: Spyder runs the script just once and jams in infinite loop.

Code that fails:

```
import tkinter as TK
ws=TK.Tk()
print('Foo')
ws.mainloop()
print('Bar')
```

When run from Spyder the window emerges and only the `Foo` is printed. When run from command line, the `Bar` is printed when the window is closed, as expected.

Adding the `manloop` killing button does not help either, the behaviour is the same.

```
import tkinter as TK
ws=TK.Tk()

Button(
    ws,
    text='Exit',
    command=lambda:ws.destroy()
).pack(expand=True)

print('Foo')
ws.mainloop()
print('Bar')
```

When the `destroy()` method call is replaced by `quit()` call the `Bar` is printed but the window is not closed.

The little expanded code works partially as intended:

```
import tkinter as TK

class FooBar:
    def __init__(self,Name):
    self.win=TK.Tk()
    self.win.title=(Name)

    def terminate(self):
        self.win.quit()
        self.win.destroy()

ws=FooBar('FooBar')

TK.Button(
    ws.win,
    text='Exit',
    command=lambda:ws.terminate()
).pack(expand=True)

print('Foo')
ws.win.mainloop()
print('Bar')
```

Even this code runs differently from the Spyder and from the command line. Form command line the `Bar` is printed no matter how the window is terminated; by the `Exit` button or the cross button. On the other hand, Spyder closes the window and prints `Bar` only if the window is closed by the `Exit` button. When closed as a window, the `Bar` is not printed and it is still stuck in the loop.

What causes this behaviour and how can I prevent it?

Comment: _"When run from command line, the Bar is printed as expected."_ - I certainly wouldn't expect that. You shouldn't see "Bar" printed until the program exits.

Comment: That was the point. See the `Bar` after the window is closed.

Comment: See the "Bar" after the window is closed when running in Spyder 5.  So try upgrading Spyder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try

```
import tkinter as TK


class FooBar:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.win = TK.Tk()
        self.win.title = name
        self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.terminate)

    def terminate(self):
        self.win.destroy()


ws = FooBar('FooBar')

TK.Button(
    ws.win,
    text='Exit',
    command=ws.terminate
).pack(expand=True)

print('Foo')
ws.win.mainloop()
print('Bar')
```

`self.win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.terminate)` might help with this. `self.win.destroy()` should work but I don't have experience with Spyder to be sure about it.

**OP's EDIT**:

It seems it was the `protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")` missing.

```
import tkinter as TK

ws=TK.Tk()
ws.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ws.destroy)

TK.Button(
    ws,
    text='Exit',
    command=ws.destroy
).pack(expand=True)

print('Foo')
ws.mainloop()
print('Bar')
```

Now the `Bar` is printed after the window is closed, no matter how, when called from both Spyder and Command Line.

Comment: I have removed the class workaround and it worked. But the question remains - Why does Spyder behives differently and how the other IDEs behive?